# Renaming my video files as per the resoltuion using batch

Tags: windows, video, batch-file, cmd, mediainfo

I would like to rename my video files as per the resolution they are in, e,g for a video 'bla bla.mp4' in 1080p, I would like to rename it to 'bla bla [H.264 1080p]. The script should automatically be able to detect the resolution of the video, and also if the file has been already renamed it should not rename it.I wasn't able to find a way to check for the resolution, so I tried to use this for 1080p files:

```
    FOR /r %%a in (*.mp4) DO (IF EXIST *[H.264*.mp4 (
    ECHO Already done) 
    ELSE (
    REN "%%~a" "%%~na [H.264 1080p].mp4"))
```

But what it does is it checks for the same file again and again which has already been renamed and therefore the reply always is 'Already done'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is beyond the scope of an SO question. Nevertheless I will answer it, because today is sunday.

- download and install [mediainfo](/questions/tagged/mediainfo) command line version
- add the path to the `mediainfo` binaries to your system or user `PATH` environment variable
- copy the rename script, replace the path to your video folder, there is a safety `echo` before the `rename` command, remove it if the output looks good
- the script tests for already-exists **and** already-processed files (suggested by Peter Wright)

---

rename script:

```
@echo off & setlocal
cd X:\video\path
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.mp4') do (
    set "fnameo=%%~ni"
    set "fnamee=%%~xi"
    set "Height="
    for /f "delims=" %%j in ('mediainfo "--Inform=Video;%%Height%%" "%%~i"') do set "Height=%%j" 
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    call set "selftest=%%fnameo:[H.264 !Height!p]=%%"
    if "!selftest!" equ "!fnameo!" if not exist "!fnameo! [H.264 !Height!p]!fnamee!" (
        echo rename "!fnameo!!fnamee!" "!fnameo! [H.264 !Height!p]!fnamee!"
    )
    endlocal
)
```

---

output example:

```
rename "Handbrake.0.9.8.mp4" "Handbrake.0.9.8 [H.264 800p].mp4"
rename "Hybrid.2012.10.21.1.mp4" "Hybrid.2012.10.21.1 [H.264 800p].mp4"
rename "Womble.mp4" "Womble [H.264 1080p].mp4"
```

Comment: I'd suggest you filter out filenames of the form `"*[*].mp4"` else you'll be renaming already-processed files that existed BEFORE the `dir` is executed. The obvious tool would be `findstr` - but with a twist since the required mask contains important characters as far as establishing the appropriate regular expression is concerned... :)

Comment: @PeterWright thanks, thats a good idea. I will look at my friend `findstr` :)

Comment: Thanks a ton! 
While this solves my problem with renaming the files as per the resolution it again renames the files which have already been renamed?
Any solution?

Comment: @MohammadNairAalam I changed the code recently for already-processed files.

Comment: @Endoro... While the first one worked quite well the changes to the code just cause the cmd window to crash now...

Answer (score 1):

There was a very similar question here:
[Windows batch file renames filename unexplainably in FOR loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17204571/windows-batch-file-renames-filename-unexplainably-in-for-loop)

Peter Wright had posted a solution with a very good explanation:

> Try
>
> for /f "delims=" %%a in (' dir /b /a-d *.mp3') do ( The problem is
>   that your original syntax finds the next filename - which finds your
>   renamed file since the new filename (with the prefix) is logically
>   'greater than' the old.
>
> Using dir builds a list of filenames, and processes the list once it
>   has been completely built - hence the list doesn't vary as the files
>   are renamed.
>
> The "delims=" clause ensures that the default parsing of the filename
>   is ineffective - otherwise, the filename would be interpreted as a
>   series of [space-separated] tokens.
>
> answered Jun 20 at 4:28 Peter Wright

Answer (score 0):

The IF EXIST conditional will always pass after the first file is renamed, since as written it will check for the existence of any file in the directory that contains "[H.264" in the file name, not just %%a.

Consult [Batch file: Find if substring is in string (not in a file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005951/batch-file-find-if-substring-is-in-string-not-in-a-file) to learn how to find "[H.264" in %%a, which would cause the intended result.