# Using a batch script for only a few specified extensions

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, rename

This is related to my earlier question [Renaming my video files as per the resoltuion using batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258480/renaming-my-video-files-as-per-the-resoltuion-using-batch)

The final script was as:

```
@echo off & setlocal
cd X:\video\path
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.mp4') do (
    set "fnameo=%%~ni"
    set "fnamee=%%~xi"
    set "Height="
    for /f "delims=" %%j in ('mediainfo "--Inform=Video;%%Height%%" "%%~i"') do set "Height=%%j" 
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    call set "selftest=%%fnameo:[H.264 !Height!p]=%%"
    if "!selftest!" equ "!fnameo!" if not exist "!fnameo! [H.264 !Height!p]!fnamee!" (
        rename "!fnameo!!fnamee!" "!fnameo! [H.264 !Height!p]!fnamee!"
    )
    endlocal
)
```

I find myself in a problem, it is that while the above script can only be used only for mp4 files most of my 480p videos are in flv format. Is there a way I could extend the same script to flv files.
I know about wildcards, but I can't use them. Using 'star.*' would rename my *.bat file as well evreytime and I cannot possibly use '?'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put more extensions in the for loop command, example:

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d *.mp4 *.flv *.mkv') do (
```